# Can I use external SourceMap files with different extensions

Tags: javascript, html, css, source-maps

Will a SourceMap with a file extension that's not `.map` (maybe `.map.js` instead) work within a browser when linked?

```
//# sourceMappingURL=../maps/runfirst.js.map.js
```

and

```
//# sourceMappingURL=../maps/styles.css.map.css
```

I'm in the rather unfortunate situation where our platform is charging $$$ mega-bucks to allow us to upload `.map` files to our own website.

Will the above work? Is there any other way to include a `.map` file without giving it a `.map` extension?

Comment: The root of the problem is your hosting provider. Move out and find a real one. :D

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer don't tease me :( I don't have a choice.